New user not being registered in mongodb from nodejs and express
I have developed an API using Node.js to facilitate user creation and management. Each user is granted the privilege to book visits to properties within the system. While user registration and authentication functionalities operate smoothly, an issue arises when attempting to book visits. Upon initiation of a booking request, an Axios error is encountered, indicating that the user ID associated with the request is null. Despite thorough examination of the MongoDB database, it has been confirmed that newly registered users are not persisting in the system. Despite efforts to diagnose and rectify the issue, including the utilization of ChatGPT for guidance, the root cause of the error remains elusive.
The code for user controll for bookingvisit is as followed:
export const bookVisit = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, date } = req.body;
  const { id } = req.params;

  try {
    const alreadyBooked = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email },
      select: { bookedVisits: true },
    });

    if (alreadyBooked.bookedVisits.some((visit) => visit.id === id)) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "This residency is already booked by you" });
    } else {
      await prisma.user.update({
        where: { email: email },
        data: {
          bookedVisits: { push: { id, date } },
        },
      });
      res.send("your visit is booked successfully");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
});

The usercontrol for creating user is as followed;
export const createUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Creating a user...");

  const { email, name, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !name || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email, name, and password are required" });
  }

  try {
    const userExists = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    if (userExists) {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: "User already registered" });
    }

    const newUser = await prisma.user.create({ data: { email, name, password } });
    console.log("User created:", newUser);

    return res.status(201).json({
      message: "User registered successfully",
      user: newUser,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error creating user:", err.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

Please note for already created user "xyz@gmail.com" that i created myself while building api is working fine, and if i add new user to the cluster, it works out too.
help me out I am junior backend developer
To try to sort this issue out i tried to add some validations so the system ensures the user is created, this is what i did to the code block for createuser
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { prisma } from "../config/prismaConfig.js";

export const createUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Creating a user...");

  const { email, name, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !name || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email, name, and password are required" });
  }

  try {
    const userExists = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    if (userExists) {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: "User already registered" });
    }

    const newUser = await prisma.user.create({ data: { email, name, password } });
    console.log("User created:", newUser);

    return res.status(201).json({
      message: "User registered successfully",
      user: newUser,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error creating user:", err.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});


it didnt work out, i tried to extract email and its content, i guess i am missing something

How did you pass userId for bookVisit?Share the exact url and route for accessing bookVisit.
